# Rails code quality tools that I can run in development mode without sharing my code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, dry, code-metrics, code-climate

I came across https://codeclimate.com.
Super awesome, *but* I'm working on a project whose code I cannot share with others or Code Climate.

Now I would like to be able to improve my code quality and wonder if anyone can suggest tools that do what codeclimate.com does but locally in development mode, without me having to share my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metric_fu gem seems to be the best option combining all known test tools into 1 an generate a neat report although its not as nice and fully featured as code climate.com

Comment: Not yet! 5.0 is coming!

Comment: For a roll-your-own, you can use Flog, Flay, Brakeman, and Simplecov and make a code styler such as rubocop, tailor, or cane, or even Rails best practices. See https://github.com/metricfu/metric_fu/wiki/Code-Tools

Comment: @BF4: Sorry what do you mean with "5.0 is coming"? EDIT: Ah sorry your the author of metric_fu ;) What features do you plan in 5.0 that make it more like code metrics?

Comment: Well, firstly, I'm not trying to make it like anything else.  For me, 5.0 means pluggable metrics which means the api is clean enough that all the various aspects of running the metrics, storing its output, graphing, formatting, and weighting as a hotspot are easy enough to do and can be configured in one place.

Answer (score 0):

We can use [Fog](https://github.com/seattlerb/flog) gem which give code complexity at class and method level. 
To check code duplications we can use [Flay](https://github.com/seattlerb/flay) gem.

Both give same result that code climate gives.

Answer (score 0):

Now there's an exact answer: Last year Code Climate released a new platform which includes [a command-line interface, Code Climate CLI](https://github.com/codeclimate/codeclimate). It runs entirely on your computer (in a Docker container) and doesn't require a Code Climate account.